# Certification Authority Error ID 44 Error Code 0x80040112

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

I had a windows server SP2 with the CA role activated, so the domain users could ask for a personal certificate. Suddenly, the Certification authority role has stoped, and when I try to bring it up it give me this error:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CertificationAuthority" Guid="{...}" EventSourceName="CertSvc" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="49754">44</EventID> 
<Version>0</Version> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-03-08T09:13:22.000000000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>6698</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>...</Computer> 
<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
</System>
- <EventData Name="MSG_E_POLICY_ERROR">
<Data Name="PolicyModuleDescription">Predeterminado de Windows</Data> 
<Data Name="MethodName">Initialize</Data> 
<Data Name="ErrorCode">0x80040112 (-2147221230)</Data> 
<Data Name="param4" /> 
<Data Name="ErrorString">No hay licencia de uso de la clase</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide error message in English.

Comment: This is the error in english.
0x80040112 CLASS_E_NOTLICENSED 
Class is not licensed for use.

Sorry for that